# AngularJS: display an OS "file save" dialog but not actually save

Tags: javascript, angularjs

All I need to do, on an `ng-click` open a file "save" dialog from the browser, cross-platform.  I am not trying to actually save anything; this is a demo/prototype only and I want to show the flow to stakeholders.

Every answer I find on SO are complex ways to save the contents of the window or a file blob, but I don't need to do that.

I am hoping for something similar to $window.prompt, but for the file dialog.

Is there anything?

Comment: you can use `<input type="file">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off azad's comment, you can use a hidden `<input type="file">` and trigger it with a `<label>`.

**Edit:** style the `<label>` to look like a button for better browser compatibility.

```css
#download {
  display: none;
}
.download-button {
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #3498db;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.download-button:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
}
```

```html
<input id="download" type="file" />
<label for="download" class="download-button">
  Save As
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anchor tag with the download attribute.

```
<a href="#" download="defaultfilename">Click me</a>
```